# ключи одинаковые значения разные GET параметры

Tags: php, get

Как обработать такую ссылку?

https://auto.yandex.ru/offers?sort_offers=relevance-desc&mark=audi&mark=toyota&mark=bmw

по ссылке передано несколько марок с разными значениями а ключи одинаковые, как такое обработать?

пробовал у себя http://test.loc/?r=1&r=2&r=3

```
print_r($_GET['r'])// результат 3
```

а как получить все значения?

Comment: а почему вы решили, что Яндекс получает значения из урла на PHP?

Comment: не важно на чем, важно как решили

Answer (score 2):

таким образом никак, формируйте ссылку по другому... можно конешно парсить урл как строку и вытягивать все совпадения - но это очень некрасиво и костыльно.
получить всю строку запроса можно через $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] и уже его парсить...

Comment: Думаете яндекс так решил, парсил урл строку?

Comment: не знаю, но через массив $_GET до всех r точно не доберетесь

Comment: @Борис, думаю Яндекс не пишет на PHP ...

Comment: Я в этом более чем уверен)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url('https://auto.yandex.ru/offers?sort_offers=relevance-desc&mark=audi&mark=toyota&mark=bmw');
if (preg_match_all("/(?P[\w\-\_]+)=(?P[^=&]+)/isu", $url['query'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $url['query'] = [];
    foreach ($matches as $item) {
        $item['value'] = urldecode($item['value']);
        if (!isset($url['query'][$item['key']])) {
            $url['query'][$item['key']] = $item['value'];
            continue;
        }

        if (!is_array($url['query'][$item['key']])) {
            $url['query'][$item['key']] = [$url['query'][$item['key']], $item['value']];
        } else {
            $url['query'][$item['key']][] = $item['value'];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($url);
/**
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["host"]=>
  string(14) "auto.yandex.ru"
  ["path"]=>
  string(7) "/offers"
  ["query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sort_offers"]=>
    string(14) "relevance-desc"
    ["mark"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "audi"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "toyota"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "bmw"
    }
  }
}
**/
```

Comment: Возможно, регулярку придется поправить, но мне кажется, должно работать.

Comment: А вообще яндекс генерирует невалидный URL . Оно, конечно, красивее выглядит, чем mark[]=audi&mark[]=..., но я не сторонник таких решений.

Answer (score 0):

если есть возможность сменить язык программирования для реализации даной задачи то используйте например python + Flask распарсивая гет-параметры так:

```
request.args.getlist('r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ссылку нужно формировать как массив. Например вот так:
http://test.loc/?r[0]=1&r[1]=2&r[2]=3
в `$_GET['r']` у вас так же запишется массив. Это решение для PHP

Если будете использовать NodeJS, то там ссылки без `[]` нормально обрабатываются. Т.е. нода сама преобразует все r в один массив

Answer (score -1):

Например так,

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
echo $key." = ".$value."</br>";
}
```

Но все одно только последнее значение останется

Comment: верно, а как яндекс решил этот вопрос?

Comment: видимо так же, как описал коллега Борис.

Comment: @bemulima $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] например

Comment: интересно, очень близко ответили

Answer (score -1):

Вот так попробуйте, должно положить в массив $_GET['r'] все 3 значения

http://test.loc/?r[]=1&r[]=2&r[]=3

Comment: Исходную строку генерирует не автор, ему нужно именно разобрать входящие данные